# make links within an iframe replace parent document

Tags: html, iframe

I'm having a web-site where most of the content will be loaded in a full-sized `iframe`.

I don't control the `iframe` itself, only the parent web-site that references the `iframe`.

When someone clicks on a link within the `iframe`, I want it to be loaded in place of my site, such that the user can always bookmark the page, and it'd be the correct page that's bookmarked.

Tried `target='_parent'` as an attribute for the `iframe`, but it didn't seem to work.

Looking for a solution that's HTML5-compliant, no JavaScript.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure a JavaScript solution would even be possible, because of a distinct origin issue. :/

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, it would seem like the [`seamless`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-seamless) attribute does this; but it's experimental and not supported by most browsers yet; plus it also has many other side-effects and comes with restrictions of its own (it looks like one won't be able to use it between documents of different origins).